# R - replace all values smaller than a specific value in a column with the nearest bigger value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this one:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), c(0,23,55,0,1,40,21))
names(df) <- c("a", "b")

  a  b
  1  0
  2 23
  3 55
  4  0
  5  1
  6 40
  7 21
```

Now I want to replace all values smaller than 22 in column `b` with the nearest bigger value. Of course it is possible to use loops, but since I have quite big datasets this is way too slow.

The solution should look somewhat like this:

```
  a  b
  1 23
  2 23
  3 55
  4 55
  5 40
  6 40
  7 40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` possibility (but note @phiver's comment on replacement ambiguities)

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    mutate(b = ifelse(b < 22, NA, b)) %>%
    fill(b) %>%
    fill(b, .direction = "up");
#  a  b
#1 1 23
#2 2 23
#3 3 55
#4 4 55
#5 5 55
#6 6 40
#7 7 40
```

Explanation: Replace values `b < 22` with `NA` and then use `fill` to fill `NA`s with previous/following non-`NA` entries.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), b = c(0,23,55,0,1,40,21))
```

Comment: It's not the required output though (see line 5)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Ah I missed that. You're right... It seems `fill` is not the correct strategy after all...

Comment: Actually the solution is ok for me because I have about 60,000 values and just needed a way to clean out some noise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zoo::rollapply` :

```
library(zoo)
df$b <- rollapply(df$b,3,function(x)
  if (x[2] < 22) min(x[x>22]) else x[2],
  partial =T)

# df
#   a  b
# 1 1 23
# 2 2 23
# 3 3 55
# 4 4 55
# 5 5 40
# 6 6 40
# 7 7 40
```

In base `R` you could do this for the same output:

```
transform(df, b = sapply(seq_along(b),function(i)
  if (b[i] < 22) {
    bi <- c(b,Inf)[seq(i-1,i+1)]
    min(bi[bi>=22])
  } else b[i]))
```

Comment: @Igor, don't edit posts with your improvement suggestions or alternate solutions, better to post your own answer or put your improvement suggestion in comments.

Comment: in this case your suggestion : `df$b[df$b < 22] <- min(df$b[df$b > 22], na.rm= TRUE)` doesn't give the expected output

Comment: Re `I am not allowed to answer questions or to make comments because I do not have enough point on stackoverflow. Thus making edits is the only way I know to answer the question`. Then answer some questions and earn your privileges ;). don't fight the system, embrace it.

Comment: privileges are required to comments as far as I know, not to answer

Comment: @Igor Also note that trying to force-edit *multiple* answers (you clearly tried with both answers here) is definitely *not* winning you any sympathies.